# Google Cloud Builder - vuejs, gulp build fails

Tags: vue.js, gulp, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-container-registry

## Problem

I'm working on adding a couple additional build steps to our current, functional build pipeline. The problem is gulp is failing to find modules when it comes to compiling the JavaScript. Below you will find the relevant section of our cloudbuild.yaml, and the bash scripts.

## Expected Results

I need the Vue.js and SCSS to processed and prepared for deployment to our production environment. Overall, our goal is to remove the transpiled JS and CSS from our Git repository, and only have the source we work with in the repo.

## Supporting Code

#### cloudbuild.yaml:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-9.10.0'
  id: npm-install
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      sh nodeprep.sh
  waitFor: ['-']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-9.10.0'
  id: gulp-build
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
      sh gulpprep.sh
  waitFor: ['npm-install']
```

#### nodeprep.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install --production
npm rebuild node-sass --force # necessary to resolve architecture differences
```

#### gulpprep.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
node_modules/.bin/gulp deploy-build --production
```

## Errors

Depending on the `--production` flag, we receive different errors. Here's the error we receive with the `--production` flag set as shown above in `nodeprep.sh`:

```
: events.js:165
:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
:       ^
: 
: Error: Cannot find module 'Axios' from '/workspace/js/vue-mini-apps/ha/src'
:     at /workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
:     at process (/workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
:     at ondir (/workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
:     at load (/workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
:     at onex (/workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
:     at /workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
:     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
: Emitted 'error' event at:
:     at Labeled.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/read-only-stream/index.js:28:44)
:     at Labeled.emit (events.js:180:13)
:     at Labeled.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/stream-splicer/index.js:130:18)
:     at Labeled.emit (events.js:180:13)
:     at Deps.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/stream-splicer/index.js:130:18)
:     at Deps.emit (events.js:180:13)
:     at /workspace/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:361:30
:     at onresolve (/workspace/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:179:25)
:     at /workspace/node_modules/browserify/index.js:490:22
:     at /workspace/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:265:24
2018/06/28 14:39:32 status changed to "ERROR"
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm@sha256:43d8b9b86f899f5622a668c7d7ad7493a323740440cf79089953cddc17a4ad2a" failed: exit status 1
2018/06/28 14:39:35 Build finished with ERROR status
```

This is the output when `--production` is removed:

```
Step #1 - "gulp-build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-9.10.0
Starting Step #1 - "gulp-build"
Step #1 - "gulp-build": module.js:545
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     throw err;
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     ^
Step #1 - "gulp-build": 
Step #1 - "gulp-build": Error: Cannot find module '../lib/completion'
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/.bin/gulp:13:18)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
Step #1 - "gulp-build":     at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
Finished Step #1 - "gulp-build"
2018/06/28 16:24:44 status changed to "ERROR"
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm@sha256:43d8b9b86f899f5622a668c7d7ad7493a323740440cf79089953cddc17a4ad2a" failed: exit status 1
```

Moving `node_modules` out of the directory returns these errors:

```
: 
: > proj@ build /workspace
: > cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify js/vue-mini-apps/materials/app.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > js/vue-mini-apps/dist/materials.js
: 
: module.js:545
:     throw err;
:     ^
: 
: Error: Cannot find module '../dist'
:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
:     at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/.bin/cross-env:3:1)
:     at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
:     at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
: module.js:545
:     throw err;
:     ^
: 
: Error: Cannot find module '../tools/node'
:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
:     at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs:6:16)
:     at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
:     at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
: npm
:  ERR! 
: errno 1
: npm ERR! proj@ build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify js/vue-mini-apps/materials/app.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > js/vue-mini-apps/dist/materials.js`
: npm ERR! Exit status 1
: npm ERR!
:  
: npm ERR! Failed at the proj@ build script.
: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
: 
: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
: npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2018-06-28T22_33_47_659Z-debug.log
```

The builds are successful on localhost, and are failing when running this command:

`container-builder-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false .`

## Attempted (and entirely unsuccessful) Solutions

Once this is functioning with `container-builder-local`, I'll be able to test it on GCP. Right now, I'm pretty well stuck as I've done everything I can think of at this point, including:

- `rm -rf node_modules` as the first command in `nodeprep.sh`
- `npm cache clear` just to be sure (npm complains and recommends `npm cache verify` instead, still appears to have no effect)
- adding `npm run-script build` (which runs `cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify js/vue-mini-apps/materials/app.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > js/vue-mini-apps/dist/materials.js`).
- I've even tried moving `node_modules` out of the project directory, so
  `npm install` has no choice but to create a new `node_modules` directory -- this causes gulp to not be installed at all when `npm install` runs.

I'm kind of at a loss as to what I should do next. It seems the deeper I go down this rabbit hole, the more progressively broken these build steps are getting.

Comment: Hey Tom, would you be able to share a reproduction setup?

Comment: @PhilippeModard just an update: I'm working on putting together a PoC that replicates this issue for your team. Thank you again.

Comment: @TomJ any updates on this?

Comment: @ShadyAnwar unfortunately, no. I'm no longer with the company where this was an issue and we were never able to implement a functional solution.